# Optionals in superclass causing problems in subclass initializer

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type

I have the following code:

```
class Being {
    var age: Int?
}


class Person: Being {
    var name: String
    enum gender { case male, female }
    var gender: gender

    init(age: Int, name: String, gender: gender) {
        super.init() // Error: Property 'self.name' not initialized at super.init call
        super.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
    }
}
```

But initializing `self.name` before calling `super.init()` generates another error (self used beefore super.init call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the optional age with var age = 0, you still have the same compiler error. Probably you didn't notice the error before changing the code and recompiling.

The problem is that you have to initialize all the properties of your class before calling the superclass initializer:

```
init(age: Int, name: String, gender: gender) {
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    super.init() // Error: Property 'self.name' not initialized at super.init call
    super.age = age
}
```